# $p$-hacking and nested models

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, anova

I have a model $\vec{y}=X\vec{\beta}+\vec{\varepsilon}$ with guassian independent errors $\vec{\varepsilon}\sim N(\vec{0},\sigma^2I_n)$. Let $n$ denote the number of rows of $X$ and $d$ denote the rank of $X$. I would like to test several hypotheses of the form:

$\vec{\beta}\in T_1,\quad \vec{\beta}\in T_2, \quad \vec{\beta}\in T_3...  \quad \vec{\beta}\in T_n$

where $T_1\subset T_2\subset T_3...$ are a chain of subspaces. For example, in two-way ANOVA, $T_1$ might be the subspace of "all means equal across all treatments and categories" and $T_2$ might be the subspace of "mean depends on treatment and not the category", $T_3$ might be the subspace of "mean depends on treatment and category in a way that factors without interaction". My goal is to test these hypotheses without $p$ hacking.

Letting $S=col(X)$, $S_{T_i}=X(T_i)$, and $S'_{T_i}$ the orthogonal complement of $T_i$ in $S$, under the hypothesis $\vec{\beta}\in T_i$, I have:

$\frac{\|{\rm proj}_{S'_{T_i}}(\vec{y}-X\beta)\|^2/\dim(S'_{T_i})}{\hat{\sigma}^2}=\frac{\|{\rm proj}_{S'_{T_i}}(\vec{y})\|^2/\dim(S'_{T_i})}{\hat{\sigma}^2}\sim F(\dim(S'_{T_i}),n-d)$

I want to test these hypotheses. Presumably, under the assumption that the early $T_i$ are easily falsifiable and the later ones are harder to falsify, the individual $p$ values for each test will start very low and get higher for the larger $T_i$.

This obviously is very different from looking at independent hypothesis tests and $p$-hacking ones way to rejecting a true hypothesis. After all, if $\beta\in T_k$ is rejected, then one probably expects $\beta\in T_{i<k}$ to be rejected as well. But I'm still concerned about $p$-hacking - is there a way to make rigorous this procedure of sequentially testing hypotheses and rejecting until a certain $p$-value is hit?

Comment: Look at "fixed sequence testing."

Comment: Thanks! For future readers this link: https://www2.cscc.unc.edu/impact7/system/files/Bretz_Slides.pdf suggests stopping at the first point where $p>\alpha$ and rejecting all previous hypotheses, so my concern about $p$-hacking (multiplicity) is unfounded. I'll have to think about why no additional correction is needed

Comment: Note that "fixed sequence testing" is just a special case of "closed testing." Also note that the fixed sequence must be pre-specified, i.e., not data-driven.

Comment: Yeah, 100%. Also I've made sense of the logical issue - suppose $T_k$ is the first hypothesis which is true, and let $\alpha$ be threshold. With probability $1-\alpha$, I will fail to reject $T_k$ (causing me to stop) and thus with probability $1-\alpha$ I reject no true hypothesis. What happens in the $\alpha$ scenario where I do not reject $T_k$ does not impact this.